# How to create this kind of dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm scrapping datas from several URL tables. My code allows me to get such a csv (using semi-colon as coma ... EUROPE)

```
a;1  -------- 1st URL
b;2
c;3
d;4
e;5
a;7 ---------- 2nd URL
b;3
c;5
d;8
e;9
a;9 ---------- 3rd URL
b;3
y;5
```

The ---URL are not part of the CSV. It's just to show you where datas for URL1 begin, and so on.
I never know in advance how much fields an URL is gonna contain and what are the fields he is gonna contain. 
I want to get to a CSV well-organized looking like this (with the example) :

```
Name ; 1stUrl ;2ndURl ;3rd Url
a;1;7;9
b;2;3;3
c;3;5;ø
d;4;8;ø
e;5;9;ø
y;ø;ø;5
```

I don't care very much about the order of the a,b,c,d. The fields can be in the ordre they prefer most.

The thing is i have two problems : 
- when the code encounter a new field, it must add it to the list of field (example of the 'y' field). 
- the code must leave a blank/vacuumed space ;ø; when there is no key in the URL for that field.

I've tried something poorly but that's clearly not it. Even conceptually, i'm not there.

```
from collections import *
import csv

def parse_csv(content, delimiter = ';'):
  csv_data = []
  for line in content.split('\n'):
    csv_data.append( [x.strip() for x in line.split( delimiter )] ) # strips spaces also
  return csv_data


s =parse_csv(open('raw.csv','rU', encoding='utf8').read())
print(len(s))
dic = defaultdict(list)
for n in range(0,len(s)):
    if (len(s[n]) == 2):
        key = s[n][0]
        val = s[n][1]
        print(key)
        print(val)


writer = csv.writer(open('dict.csv', 'w',encoding='utf8'), delimiter=';')
for key, value in dico.items():
   writer.writerow([key, value])
```

What do you think of it ?
Any help would be appreciated guys :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib.request
from collections import *


def parse_csv(content, delimiter = ';'):  ##We use here ";" to parse CSV because of the European way of dealing with excel-csv
  csv_data = []
  for line in content.split('\n'):
    csv_data.append( [x.strip() for x in line.split( delimiter )] ) # strips spaces also
  return csv_data

List_of_list_of_pairs=[]
List_of_pairs=[]

list_url=parse_csv(open('url.csv','rU').read())


for i in range(0,len(list_url)) :
    List_of_pairs = []

    url=str(list_url[i][0]) ## read URL from an array coming from an Url-CSV
    page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup_0 = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),"html.parser")
    restricted_webpage= soup_0.find( "div", {"id":"ingredients"} )
    readable_restricted=str(restricted_webpage)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(readable_restricted,"html.parser")


    trs = soup.find_all('tr')

    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.find_all("td")

        try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. This allows the program to continue after encountering an error.
            Nutriments = str(tds[0].get_text().strip())
            print(Nutriments)
        # This structure $isolate the item by its column in the table and converts it into a string.
            Quantity = str(tds[1].get_text().strip())
            print(Quantity)
            Pair=[Nutriments,Quantity]
            List_of_pairs.append(Pair)

        except:
            print ("bad tr string")
            continue #This tells the computer to move on to the next item after it encounters an error
    List_of_list_of_pairs.append(List_of_pairs)

print(List_of_list_of_pairs)
dico = defaultdict(list)

for n,list_of_pairs in enumerate(List_of_list_of_pairs):
    for i,pairs in enumerate(list_of_pairs):
        if (len(pairs) == 2):
             cle = pairs[0]
             val = pairs[1]
             while (len(dico[cle]) < n):
                   dico[cle].append('ND')
             dico[cle].append(val)
for cle in dico:
    while (len(dico[cle]) < n):
            dico[cle].append('ND')


import csv
with open("dict2csv.csv", 'w',encoding='utf8') as outfile:
   csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,)

   for k,v in dico.items():
       csv_writer.writerow([k] + v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have `list` objects as value for your `dict`. So it is as simple as:

```
content = """a;1
b;2
c;3
d;4
e;5
a;7
b;3
c;5
d;8
e;9
a;9
b;3
y;5"""

csv_data = []
for line in content.split('\n'):
    csv_data.append( [x.strip() for x in line.split(';')] )

s = csv_data
dic = {}
for n in range(0,len(s)):
    if (len(s[n]) == 2):
        key = s[n][0]
        val = s[n][1]
        if key not in dic:
            dic[key] = []
        dic[key].append(val)
```

And now `dic` is:

```
{'a': ['1', '7', '9'],
 'b': ['2', '3', '3'],
 'c': ['3', '5'],
 'd': ['4', '8'],
 'e': ['5', '9'],
 'y': ['5']}
```

Which is what you wanted I guess.

On a side note, I would strongly advise you never to use `from package_xx import *` because it can clutter your environment.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. But i'm not sure that works precisely as i want it to work. I wasn't very clear and i'm sorry for that. Indeed, in your final dic, we don't have the information than in the field 'y', 5 comes from the third URL. Indeed, it is placed in the first position, right below, a1 which come form the first URL .

Comment: okay and how do you know when a url is finished ? Is there like a "stop code" to know one url is finished and another one begins ?

Comment: No. There is not. Now there is a list of list of pairs that allows me to know when a URL stops. It works now. I'll update a working' answer.